# Using Render Doc with Maya

Tags: opengl, debugging, maya

I am creating a plug-in that utilizes OpenGL to render to a seperate device however the plugin is only showing a black screen I suspect due to an OpenGL error. However, when I try and attach Render doc to the process, I am unable to get any data out.

I am unable to start maya with render doc as it stops at what appears to be asking for licensing and quits. If I inject into the process after maya is started I can get a connection however the API always says none and no data is transmitted.

I have tried a few of the common tools listed when searching for tools like render doc and they all seem to have build or run issues.

Is there some other common tool for debugging an open gl application in maya ? or Has anyone successfully used Render Doc with Maya?